# how to compare NSDecimalNumber in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdecimalnumber

I have a price field which a `NSDecimalNumber`.  I want to create a condition if the value is.

I tried the following:

```
- (NSString *)numberToPriceString:(NSDecimalNumber *)price{
    NSDecimalNumber *zero = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:@"0"];
    if (price == zero){

    }else{

    }
```

However the zero value shows a debug value of `@"0"`.

How do I create a zero value equal to something I can catch the condition with?

Comment: Mostly this would involve actually reading the documentation on NSDecimalNumber.

Comment: Not even that, compare: will do the job just fine!

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, don't use `==` for comparing objects in Objective-C, unless you're really sure that the pointer values comparison is what you need. In other words, `==` will return true only if you have the same instance on both sides of the operator.

The usual way to do comparison in Objective-C is to use `isEqual:` method. However, `NSDecimalNumber` is a tricky one.

You need to either use `compare:` and check the result against `NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedSame` and `NSOrderedDescending` values of `NSComparisonResult` enum or `isEqualToNumber` and get the `BOOL` result directly.

Please refer to docs for details and tips on when to use which method: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/index.html

Comment: You can also use `isEqualToNumber:` with `NSDecimalNumber`

Comment: Fair point! I've updated the answer to mention `isEqualToNumber:` as well. Thanks.